# React.js - operationStore.getItems is not a function

Tags: javascript, server, gulp, babeljs

I'm getting the following error when running my Web App using the following command: node --harmony gulpfile.babel

Uncaught TypeError: operationStore.getItems is not a function

I'm not even close to knowing what the problem is. Here are the gulp file and where the error is occurring.

The code worked previously when declaring everything outside my app.js in the index.ejs file. But that prevented me from using es6 in the server side files, which i need. So I dead that using the -- harmony flag would allow me to use es6. But I cant get over this error that happens when I use the harmony flag.

getItems is clearly a function to me, what is happening?

Main.jsx

```
var Login = require('./auth/LogApp.jsx');
var operationStore = require('./stores/OperationStore.jsx');
var initial = operationStore.getItems();
```

Gulpfile.babel.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var LiveServer =  require('gulp-live-server');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var browserify =  require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var babelify = require('babelify');

gulp.task('live-server', function(){
    var server = new LiveServer('server/main.js');
    server.start();
})

gulp.task('bundle',['copy'], function(){
    return browserify({
        entries:'app/main.jsx',
        jquery : 'jquery-browserify',
        debug:true,
    })
        .transform(babelify,
            {
                "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"],
                "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-function-bind"],
                extensions: [".jsx", ".js",]
            })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./.tmp'));
})

gulp.task('copy', function() {
    gulp.src(['app/*.css', 'app/Icons/**/*','app/stores/**/*', 'app/helper/**/*', 'app/dispatcher.js','bundle.js', 'app/helpers/RestHelper.js',
            'app/actions/OperationActionCreator.jsx', 'app/actions/SurgeonActionCreator.jsx',
            'app/actions/PatientActionCreator.jsx','app/actions/ORActionCreator.jsx',
            'node_modules/guid/guid.js','node_modules/jquery/**/*', 'bower_components*/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./.tmp'));
})

gulp.task('serve', ['bundle', 'live-server'], function(){
    browserSync.init(null,{
        proxy:"http://localhost:7777",
        port: 9001
    })
})

gulp.run('serve')
```

OperationStore.jsx

```
var operationStore = function() {

    var operations = [];

    var listeners = [];

    var updateOperations = function(helper){
        helper.get("api/operations")
            .then(function(data){
                operations = data;
                triggerListeners(listeners);
            });
    }

    updateOperations(helper);

    function getItems(){
        return operations;
    };

    var addOperationItem = function(operation) {
        operations.push(operation);
        triggerListeners(listeners);
        helper.post("api/operations", operation);
    }

    var deleteOperationItem = function (operation) {
        var index;
        operations.filter(function (_operation, _index) {
            if (_operation.name == operation.name) {
                index = _index;
            }
        });
        operations.splice(operation, 1);
        triggerListeners(listeners);

        //added this
        helper.del('api/operations/'+ operation._id);
    }

    var onChange = function(listener){
        listeners.push(listener);
        return listeners;
    }

    var triggerListeners = function(listeners) {
        listeners.forEach(function(listener) {
            listener(operations);
        })
    }

    var registerEvent = function (event) {
        var split = event.type.split(':');
        if (split[0] === 'operation-item') {
            switch (split[1]) {
                case "add":
                    addOperationItem(event.payload);
                    break;
                case "delete":
                    deleteOperationItem(event.payload);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    var dispatchRegister = function(dispatcher) {
        dispatcher.register(registerEvent);
    }

    dispatchRegister(dispatcher);

    return {
        getItems: getItems,
        onChange: onChange,
        addOperationItem: addOperationItem,
        deleteOperationItem: deleteOperationItem,
        triggerListeners: triggerListeners,
        dispatchRegister: dispatchRegister,
        registerEvent: registerEvent,
        updateOperations: updateOperations
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was something simple yet fundamental I missed. The OperationStore.jsx needs module.exports at the end. Here the new jsx that works.

```
import RangeDate from './../components/src/range_date'

function operationStore(){
    ...
}

module .exports = new operationStore();
```